# Concatenate two rows value with same id but different column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]
How can I merge multiple rows value with the same ID

When the value in the first and second row in the same column is the same. How can I merge this?

Please see attached image.I want highlighted column

For e.g

I want to get the table:

```
A/b  ID  SUFFIX   Identify No        MERGED id
CON  123     C    12345-33344441-8   123-456
CON2 456     C1   12345-33344441-8   123-456
```

How can I merge multiple rows values with the same ID?

When the value in the first and second row in the same column is the same. How can I merge this?

For e.g

I want to get table:

```
A/b  ID   SUFFIX   Identify No            MERGED id
CON  123  C        12345-33344441-8       123-456
CON2 456  C1       12345-33344441-8       123-456
```

Comment: You show us 2 times your desired result, did you forget to show us the sample data ?

Comment: You need to show us how the original table looks like and also what you have tried. You probably need a `GROUP BY` query

Comment: Avoid loosely using the term "Merge" (which is a specific DML statement in T-SQL), please use more specific terms like concatenate, union, append, etc, which describe _specifically_ what you're trying to do.

Comment: Your `Merged-Id` column represents denormalized data, which is a bad database design smell. I think you have an X/Y Problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to concat all `ID` columns for matching `IdentityNo`
If that is so, you can do it like this

```
select t.ab,
       t.id,
       t.suffix,
       t.identifyno,
       ( select string_agg(convert(varchar(50), t1.id), '-')
         from   table1 t1
         where  t1.identifyno = t.identifyno
       ) as merged_id
from   table1 t
```

Try it yourself in this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9d4497b1b35c3f1c3099d676e92fc30d)

This approach also has no problem when the rows are ordered in such a way that the matching IdentifyNo are not nice after each other.

Assuming that is what you are after off course

**EDIT (after the OP changed the column names)**

New [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e41abab73a61de7fb48400f60e8b2dc5)

New query

```
select t.id,
       t.primary_Secondary,
       t.id2,
       t.PassportNO,
       ( select string_agg(convert(varchar(50), t1.id2), '-')
         from   table1 t1
         where  t1.PassportNO = t.PassportNO
       ) as merged_id
from   table1 t
```

Result from new query

| id | primary_Secondary | id2 | PassportNO | merged_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Pri | 242 | 12345-789 | 242-342 |
| 2 | Sec | 342 | 12345-789 | 242-342 |

Comment: ID  Primary /Secondary   ID PassPort NO Want this result Merge ID
1 Pri                             242       12345-789                       242-342
2 Sec                            342  12345-789                     242-342

Comment: Then edit your question and explain with sample data what exact you want, then I can help you

Comment: @Muhammadusmankhan My answer does exact that you asked, I used the column names you showed us not the one you wrote in the comments. But the answer does just what you ask in the comment above. If this is not the case, then please edit your question and explain what you want

Comment: @Muhammadusmankhan I edited my answer and added the query using your new column names